# Unidentified component on carburetor

Tags: carburetor, electronics

A couple of days ago I went over to a friend who owns an older KTM motorcycle and as I was having a look on his motor I noticed a component on his carburetor which looked like something electronic but had no cables attached to it. It is similar to the black component on this image.

[image]

What is this component?

Comment: Without a photo of the actual carby we couldn't say for sure.

Sounds like @Solar Mike is probably right though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would iirc be a temperature controlled choke unit, so if it is warm enough then the choke is off.

Operated by a temperature-sensitive coiled spring.

Comment: i have tried to google it with "motorcycle temperature controlled choke unit" term and some variations but i cannot find much. Most of the components and images don't look the same. Probably i will take my friends carb apart to clarify this. hehehe...